# How do I sign a file using QES(Qualified electronic signature)

Tags: digital-signature

I am to sign a PDF using a QES.

How is this done? What provider do you recommend?

Comment: Welcome to Information Security Stack Exchange! Unfortunately, questions asking for product or service recommendations are off-topic; they attract opinionated answers and spam. I'm afraid we can't help you with this.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are talking about QES as in the EU eIDAS regulation (EU Regulation No 910/2014) there are two possibilities:

- Offline electronic signature
- Remote electronic signature (kind of "QES as a service")

If you are looking for an **offline electronic signature**, you will need two things:

1. You will have to obtain an eIDAS compliant certificate from a certified provider. I makes sense to purchase such a certificate from a provider which is operating in your home country. Normally you will receive a smart card with that certificate after your identity got verified and you paid for it. Plan some time (days to weeks) for getting verified and having the card mailed to you.
2. You will need a suiteable card reader and a piece of software to perform actual signatures.

Recently the **remote electronic signature** also came to be, at least in some countries. I know it's kind of against the rules to recommend products here but in this case I hope it's OK to say that for example in Germany there is the sign-me service provided by Bundesdruckerei, for which you can register and identify yourself using the eID function of the electronic German ID card. (You can even identify yourself via video ident in case you don't have a Germany eID card because you are not a German, for example.)

In order to sign a PDF document usinng that service, you will still need a piece of software on your machine which will connect to their service and generate the signature for you, though this is a feature which is available in a number of desktop signing software products available, even free of charge.

Please note that what happens behind the scenes in that case:

They will create an account for you, generate a private key and issue a certificate for that private key and store it on their system. They will then generate the signing hash for you online on their premises, which is why it is called *remote* electronic signature.

I am not aware of any QES as a service / remote electronic signature provider where you would upload your PDF and get a signed version back, though this would be possible to implement.

NB: Originally the German eID card had been prepared to have a private key and certificate loaded onto it by some provider and would have been technically prepared to work as a signature device, yet that service never got implemented.